# Change Zoom in Power BI Maps

Tags: powerbi, bing-maps, powerbi-desktop

The default zooming behavior is almost unusable in Power BI Maps. It zooms in to a point where one can hardly distinguish the region they are looking at. Does anyone know how to modify the zooming behavior?

Comment: its zoom or turn off zoom only in the default map visual

Comment: How would you like this to work? I believe the bounding box of the data is used to zoom the map. Would it make sense to switch over to centering and a specific zoom level when the bounding box is really small?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  I zoom in one level and it halves the map view.  I need it to zoom in and out much less per zoom level.

Comment: Did you solve this? It is very annoying.